# How to click on the randomly generated link from a list of links

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In my application, there are more than 50 links starting with "pw_listing_widget_tabs_list_ul']/li". I want to click on the randomly generated link. I have written below, but it is failing to click the link.

```
    List<WebElement> links= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='pw_listing_widget_tabs_list_ul']/li"));
    int count=links.size();
    System.out.println("Total links are: " +count); 
    Random r = new Random();
    int linkNo = r.nextInt(count);
    System.out.println("Random Link# " +linkNo);
    WebElement link = links.get(linkNo);
    String text = link.getText();
    System.out.println("Text: " + text);
    Thread.sleep(3000);     
    link.click();
```

I have even tried to click the link using text, but the text is coming to long to & it is failing to click.

Comment: always print the errors you get from console

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the link (anchor tag), try to specifically point it to the tag a.

**Can you please change your XPath to**

```
//ul[@id='pw_listing_widget_tabs_list_ul']/li/a


List<WebElement> links= driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@id='pw_listing_widget_tabs_list_ul']/li/a"));
```

**Q2: I have even tried to click the link using text, but the text is coming to long to & it is failing to click.**

Ans2: Your element point to `<li>` and when u use `link.getText();`it will going to return all the text inside `<li>` and not inside `<a href="">{ANCHOR-TAG-TEXT}</a>`

```
Try to use the below XPATH:

//ul[@id='pw_listing_widget_tabs_list_ul']/li/a
```

***Note: If possible share error code and HTML***